# Updating data in listbox from datatable

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, listbox, ado.net

I want to show data from data table on form_load using list box, and later update that data from list box on button click by Insert command. Function for that is fill_List(). This is my code:

```
    OleDbConnection konekcija;
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string putanja = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        string[] putanjaBaze = putanja.Split(new string[] { "bin" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", putanjaBaze[0]);
        konekcija = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|\B31Autoplac.accdb");
    }

    void fill_List()
    {
        konekcija.Open();
        OleDbCommand komPrikaz = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM GORIVO ORDER BY GorivoID ASC", konekcija);
        adapter.SelectCommand = komPrikaz;
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string pom;
            pom = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() + " " + dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() + " " + dt.Rows[i][2];
            listBox1.Items.Add(pom);
        }
        konekcija.Close();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fill_List();
    }

private void btnUpisi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s1, s2, s3;
        s1 = tbSifra.Text;
        s2 = tbNaziv.Text;
        s3 = tbOpis.Text;

        string Upisi = "INSERT INTO GORIVO (GorivoID, Naziv, Opis) VALUES (@GorivoID, @Naziv, @Opis)";
        OleDbCommand komUpisi = new OleDbCommand(Upisi, konekcija);
        komUpisi.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GorivoID", s1);
        komUpisi.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Naziv", s2);
        komUpisi.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Opis", s3);

        string Provera = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM GORIVO WHERE GorivoID=@GorivoID";
        OleDbCommand komProvera = new OleDbCommand(Provera, konekcija);
        komProvera.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GorivoID", s1);

        try
        {
            konekcija.Open();
            int br = (int)komProvera.ExecuteScalar();
            if(br==0)
            {
                komUpisi.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Podaci su uspesno upisani u tabelu i bazu.", "Obavestenje");
                tbSifra.Text = tbNaziv.Text = tbOpis.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("U bazi postoji podatak sa ID = " + tbSifra.Text + ".", "Obavestenje");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Greska prilikom upisa podataka. " + ex1.ToString(), "Obavestenje");
        }
        finally
        {
            konekcija.Close();
            fill_List();
        }
    }
```

Instead of this 
[image: Picture with my code]

It shows me this (added duplicates with new data) 
[image: Picture how it should be]

Is there a problem in my function or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Another bug caused by global variables.
You are keeping a global variable for the DataTable filled by the fill_list method. This datatable is never reset to empty when you call fill_list, so at every call you add another set of rows to the datatable and then transfer this data inside the listbox. Use a local variable.

But the same rule should be applied also to the OleDbConnection and OleDbCommand. There is no need to keep global instances of them. Creating an object is really fast and the convenience to avoid global variables is better than the little nuisance to create an instance of the connection or the command.

```
void fill_List()
{
    using(OleDbConnection konekcija = new OleDbConnection(......))
    using(OleDbCommand komPrikaz = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM GORIVO ORDER BY GorivoID ASC", konekcija))
    {
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          konekcija.Open();
          OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(komPrikaz);
          adapter.Fill(dt);
          listBox1.Items.Clear();
          for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
          {
                string pom;
                pom = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() + " " + dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() + " " + dt.Rows[i][2];
                listBox1.Items.Add(pom);
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: I will try this one now. Thank you for a such quick response.

Answer (score 1):

`Clear` your DataTable before filling it again.

```
void fill_List()
{
    konekcija.Open();
    OleDbCommand komPrikaz = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM GORIVO ORDER BY GorivoID ASC", konekcija);
    adapter.SelectCommand = komPrikaz;
    dt.Clear(); // clear here
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        string pom;
        pom = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() + " " + dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() + " " + dt.Rows[i][2];
        listBox1.Items.Add(pom);
    }
    konekcija.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @DrNachtschatten. It helped me a lot.